# How do I convert MySQL enums to Rust enums when using the mysql crate?

Tags: mysql, rust

I want to read enums from a MySQL table, but I'm failing to convert the string enums from the table into real Rust enums.

What options do I have? The [documentation](https://docs.rs/mysql/1.2.0/mysql/value/trait.FromValue.html) tells me that I should implement the `FromValue` trait:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
mysql = "15.1.0"
strum = "0.14.0"
strum_macros = "0.14.0"
```

```
use mysql::{
    prelude::{ConvIr, FromValue},
    Value,
};
use std::str::{from_utf8, FromStr};
use strum_macros::{AsStaticStr, EnumString};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, EnumString, AsStaticStr)]
pub enum UserRole {
    ADMIN,
    USER,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct EnumIr {
    bytes: Vec<u8>,
}

impl ConvIr<UserRole> for EnumIr {
    fn new(v: Value) -> mysql::error::Result<EnumIr> {
        match v {
            Value::Bytes(bytes) => match from_utf8(&*bytes) {
                Ok(_) => Ok(EnumIr { bytes: bytes }),
                Err(_) => Err(mysql::FromValueError(Value::Bytes(bytes))),
            },
            v => Err(mysql::FromValueError(v)),
        }
    }
    fn commit(self) -> UserRole {
        unsafe { UserRole::from_str(from_utf8(&self.bytes).unwrap()).unwrap() }
    }
    fn rollback(self) -> Value {
        Value::Bytes(self.bytes)
    }
}

impl FromValue for UserRole {
    type Intermediate = EnumIr;
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
error[E0053]: method `new` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src/main.rs:20:5
   |
20 |     fn new(v: Value) -> mysql::error::Result<EnumIr> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `mysql_common::value::convert::FromValueError`, found enum `mysql::error::Error`
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(mysql_common::value::Value) -> std::result::Result<EnumIr, mysql_common::value::convert::FromValueError>`
              found type `fn(mysql_common::value::Value) -> std::result::Result<EnumIr, mysql::error::Error>`
```

Has anyone managed to do the conversion or is there a better approach altogether?

Comment: Thank you for answering! Unfortunately the rust playground does not include the mysql crate, so I can't make an example.


My problem is on 
`fn new(v: Value) -> mysql::Result<EnumIr>`
I get
`expected struct mysql_common::value::convert::FromValueError, found enum mysql::error::Error`


I tried to return mysql::FromValueError and mysql::error::FromValueError, but they both don't work. The struct mysql_common::value_convert::FromValueError however is private.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first question here, thanks for taking your time. The code above is now from a new cargo project. You should be able to copy and run it to reproduce the compiler errors.

Comment: The process you just went through is the right process to ask a question in **any** context; on Stack Overflow, in an issue tracker, in a chat, or even in person; keep that in mind and you will get much better answers (and are also likely to answer your own question more often than not).

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand about the compiler error? It says you need to return a `FromValueError` but you are returning a `mysql::error::Error`; why are you using the wrong type?

Comment: Why are you linking to the documentation for version **1.2.0** when the version you are using is **15.1.0**?

Comment: Why do you have an `unsafe` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message states (cleaned up a bit):

```
expected type `fn(Value) -> Result<EnumIr, FromValueError>`
   found type `fn(Value) -> Result<EnumIr, mysql::Error>`
```

You can't return the wrong type; that's just a fundamental condition of a statically typed language. Return the correct type instead: `Result<EnumIr, mysql::FromValueError>`.

I've also changed your code to avoid doing a spurious second parsing of the data into a string:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct EnumIr {
    string: String,
}

impl ConvIr<UserRole> for EnumIr {
    fn new(v: Value) -> Result<EnumIr, mysql::FromValueError> {
        match v {
            Value::Bytes(bytes) => match String::from_utf8(bytes) {
                Ok(string) => Ok(EnumIr { string }),
                Err(e) => Err(mysql::FromValueError(Value::Bytes(e.into_bytes()))),
            },
            v => Err(mysql::FromValueError(v)),
        }
    }

    fn commit(self) -> UserRole {
        self.string.parse().unwrap()
    }

    fn rollback(self) -> Value {
        Value::Bytes(self.string.into_bytes())
    }
}
```

It also seems like you should attempt to parse the enum in the `new` method as that's the only one that allows for a `Result`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct EnumIr {
    role: UserRole,
    string: String,
}

impl ConvIr<UserRole> for EnumIr {
    fn new(v: Value) -> Result<EnumIr, mysql::FromValueError> {
        match v {
            Value::Bytes(bytes) => match String::from_utf8(bytes) {
                Ok(string) => match string.parse() {
                    Ok(role) => Ok(EnumIr { role, string }),
                    Err(_) => Err(mysql::FromValueError(Value::Bytes(string.into_bytes()))),
                },
                Err(e) => Err(mysql::FromValueError(Value::Bytes(e.into_bytes()))),
            },
            v => Err(mysql::FromValueError(v)),
        }
    }

    fn commit(self) -> UserRole {
        self.role
    }

    fn rollback(self) -> Value {
        Value::Bytes(self.string.into_bytes())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just checked in my bigger project and yes: Your code converts the mysql row value correctly into rust enums, so cool!